# Ants Profiler shows slow performance on Glass Mapper calls

Tags: glass-mapper

Sitecore 8.2 Update 1, hosted in Azure web apps. Noticed that, every first request is very slow to load. After 2nd request, the site loads pretty quick.

We use Glass Mapper map Sitecore templates on to strongly type in our solution.

Some examples on, how we retrieve item and items includes:

**To get single item**:

```
var myModel = _contentService.GetEntity<myModel>(renderingContextItem.ToString());
```

**To get sub items**:

```
_contentService.GetEntity<IMenuItem>(navigationRootItemId)

[SitecoreChildren(IsLazy = true)]
public virtual IEnumerable<IMenuItem> SubItems { get; set; }
```

Ants profiler shows that Glass Mapper `GetModel` as HOT path below:
[image]

Would be get your thoughts on above implementation and why ANTS profiling is complaining about Glass Mapper.

Update:

Here's the code snippet :

```
 public partial class MenuItemEntity
 {
       /// <summary>
       /// Gets or sets the sub items for a menu item.
       /// </summary>
       [SitecoreChildren(IsLazy = true)]
       public virtual IEnumerable<IMenuItem> SubItems { get; set; }
 }


 public TModel GetEntity<TModel>(string identity) where TModel : class
 {
      return _context.GetItem<TModel>(identity);
 }
```

Comment: Can you post one of your models and the `GetEntity<T>` method? The reason could be also the item reads - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4924/too-much-item-reads-in-debug-mode

Comment: @TamásTárnok, sure I've updated the question with code snippets.

Comment: Glass (depending on version) used to compile the views in order to determine what model is to be used and cache the result. During first load this can cause a delay. In later versions of Glass, this was changed.

Comment: we are using glass mapper 4.2.188

Comment: Can you please post more of the ANTS call stack

Comment: @NilPun Did you ever sort this out?